# How to get data from belongsTo laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have 2 tables Users, Organization

- Users hasMany Organization
- Organization belongsTo User

**User.php**

```
public function organization()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Organization::class, 'user_id');
}
```

**Organization.php**

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Organization::class,'user_id');
}
```

Now I want to retrieve data of Organization with user

**In Controller**

```
dd( Organization::with('user')->get() );
```

but in relation, user returns null. what should I do now? Please help

[image]

Comment: try `dd( Organization::with('user')->get() );` as you added `user` relation

Comment: @KamleshPaul that was a typing mistake. it returns null thats why I post. If I user with('user') too

Comment: then add your db structure `organization` table should have `user_id` column

Comment: It already have user_id column which is a foreign key of users table's id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Organization` model the `user` relationship should be a `belongsTo` with `User` not `Organization`(self).

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Then you can load that relationship on `Organization`:

```
$org = Organization::with('user')->get();
```

Comment: it returns null

Comment: what "returns null"?

Comment: please check my edited question. I attached screenshot in question

Comment: that particular Organization you are looking at either doesn't have a `user_id` field set or there is no User matching the `user_id` set

Comment: it has user_id which is a foreign key of users->id... 
if I run ```User::with('organization')->get()``` this. It worked. but if I run vice versa it didn't work. can't understand why?

Comment: I found my fault. your answer is correct. thanks a lot. in organization I used self class. but it should User::class in belongsTo.